# Which of the following is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Which of the following is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$?

1. All vectors of the form $(0, a, a^2)$
2. All vectors of the form $(a+2, a, 0)$
3. All vectors of the form $(a, b, 2)$
4. All vectors of the form $(a, b, a-2b)$
5. None of the above.

Can you give an explanation too please?

I have 2.,3., and 4. so far, but I'm honestly kind of lost in this. Am I correct?

Comment: Which _kind_ of subspace? (2) and (3) are affine subspaces, but not linear subspaces.

Comment: Welcome to math.se!  Most of the people in this community are interested in helping people to learn and understand mathematics, but not very interested in just giving answers.  So to get some serious help which addresses what you really need to know, you should post your attempts at solving these problems.

Comment: @user4573582 What axioms are you having trouble with?

Comment: 1 is not since $a^2+b^2\neq (a+b)^2$ necessarily...

Comment: @rschwieb, #2, and #3 can't be made into <0,0,0>, so they aren't subspaces; am I correct? So it's either #4 or #5 as the answer, and I'm still working on #4.

Comment: (a+x) - 2(b+y) = c+z; c = a - 2b; x - 2y = z; so (a-2b) + (x - 2y) = c + z; So #4 is closed under addition. Now I just need to check for if it's closed under multiplication.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven for #4, I did $k(a, b, a-2b)$ and got $(ka, kb, ka-2kb)$. How do I know if this is closed under multiplication?

Comment: You can see it's closed.  Assuming your $a,b,k\in \mathbb{R}$, let $ka=c, kb=d$.  Then $k(a,b,a-2b)=(ka,kb,ka-2kb)=(c,d,c-2d)$, and since $c,d\in \mathbb{R}$, it is closed under scalar multiplication.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 2):

You can see that it is a closed subspace as follows:

Contains the $0$ vector:  $(0,0,0)=(0,0,0-2\cdot0)$

Closed under addition:  This was shown by the OP in the comments section.

Closed under scalar multiplication:
Assuming you $a,b,k\in\mathbb{R},$ let $ka=c, kb=d$.  Clearly $c,d\in\mathbb{R}$.  If it is closed then 
$$k(a,b,a-2b)$$
will be an element of the subspace for all real $k$.  So
$$k(a,b,a-2b)=(ka,kb,k(a-2b))=(ka,kb,ka-2kb)=(c,d,c-2d)$$
which is of the form that we need for the space to be closed.
Thus $\{(a,b,a-2b)|a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.